# Stream value of video stream and detected plate numberin django

Tags: django, video-streaming

I am streaming a video feed from camera using Videocapture(0) in django and passing that frame to detect license plate and in return I get 2 values image with license number and license number as a string I am currently streaming frames using Httpstreamingresponse (django response library) but with that I can only stream frames from Videocapture. I want to stream 2 values frames and license plate number could anyone tell me how to go about that

Comment: What is the model and manufacturer of your camera? Cause you might use internal API to get info about plates and picture of the plates. You can download data using JS from two different endpoints.  I think it is possible to combine response with picture and str.

Comment: yes but I dont want to combine with picture and str I want to get stream string which will change with picture

Comment: I want to stream string and video at same time in Django and I don't think that it is related to camera

Comment: Yes it is, a lot of cameras have builtin LPR (license plate recognition) and you can get both  picture and the license plate at the same time from their API

Comment: I do not completely understand what is the data flow here, so it is hard to know what you really want. Is it  videoframe -> some AI -> license number + image ? Could you provide some code maybe?

Comment: I understand that by Videocapture(0) you mean opencv and then you process the frames using opencv but why do you need to stream it?  On the frontend you can use JS to get video and current license plates if you save them to DB? if you need just a picture then send picture. You might try do it with websockets too.

Comment: @MichałDarowny I want to stream video feed on to my browser and detect the license plate from the video feed. If I detect License plate then I will have to stream that on browser with my video feed